# ACL Permission in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
(for %%a in ("C:\Test1","C:\Test2") do (
    echo Fixing Permission issue of %%a
    ICACLS %%a | findstr /i "(I)"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 ( 
        echo/
        echo Removing Inheritance from %%a
        ICACLS %%a /inheritance:d 
    )
    ICACLS %%a | findstr /i "User_1:(OI)(CI)(R)"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 
        echo/
        Echo Updating Permission of User_1
        ICACLS %%a /remove User_1
        ICACLS %%a /grant:r "User_1:(OI)(CI)(R)"
    )
)
```

I need to Remove inheritance if exist(I don't want to run removal of inheritance every time) and then apply/Remove some permission. But I think %ERRORLEVEL% of If else statement are not working perfectly. Can someone help me on that.

Comment: Use `@echo off & SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and then use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of `%ERRORLEVEL%`, see https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Answer (score 1):

Expansion takes place before any command is executed inside a block of code. Basically, anything placed within a group of parenthesises.

Because the *errorlevel* variable is already expanded before the *icacls* command is executed, the result of *icacls* doesn't affect the expression of the *if* command.

Luckily, the *errorlevel* variable has a special feature. It can be used by the *if* command without expanding it.

```
:: This is true when %errorlevel% >= 1
if errorlevel 1 (

:: This is true when %errorlevel% <= 0
if not errorlevel 1 (
```

Comment: So, you are saying that `ERRORLEVEL` is always re-evaluated on every use. Is that correct?

Comment: If you run the following command it will output *fail* and *success*: (type ?&if errorlevel 1 echo fail&type nul&if not errorlevel 1 echo success) If you remove *not* from the last if expression it will only output *fail*.